# JSON post doesn't seem to post, I get all objects instead of posting my object to the list

Tags: c#, json, post, httpwebrequest

Im trying to post data using the HttpWebRequest class. The function I am calling with the post method should add my data to a list and return the data i just added.  However, instead of posting the data I am trying to send, I get all data in the list back, which is what equivalent get method should do. This is the code:

```
    public string AddList(string title)
    {

        // Connection to service
        var uri = new Uri(url + "/method/");
        var cache = new CredentialCache();
        cache.Add(uri, "Basic", new NetworkCredential(username, password));

        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        httpWebRequest.Credentials = cache;
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "{\"title\":\"TestTitle\"}";

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
```

So Im starting to think that the API I am calling thinks that I am getting when I am actually trying to post. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

EDIT: For the record, if have tried the URL with the backslash in the end and without it, doesn't change anything.

Comment: Try to use Fiddler to check what request is actually sent.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your method with `POST` request as below. Are you sure your API method is a `POST` method. Make sure it is and in such case it should have `[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]` attribute on it.

```
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
```

Comment: I am sure it is a post method, I tried calling the method with Postman Chrome Extension and that works just fine.

Comment: Can you post your API method signature